# Javascript-- count frenquency of each String appreas and print them out from greatest to smallest

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

After the user enter a paragraph, the javascript will count the frequency of each word appreas and print them out from the greatest to smallest.  I already count the amount of each word by using two arrays. However, I do not really know how to print them out based on the amount since the counts and words are stored in two different arrays. Please help me. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> practice </title>
<style>
.field{
font-size: 10px; /
width: 400px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<p> This progam will calculate what you want to</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
<input type="text" id="paragraph" class="field",> 
<button onclick="input()"><b>Submit</b></button>


<script>
function input() {
var test = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
var arr =[];
 arr = test.toLowerCase().split(" ");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;

function foo(arr) {

    var a = [], b = [], prev;

    arr.sort();
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }

   return [a, b];
}

 var result = foo(arr);
document.write('[' + result[0] + ']<br>[' + result[1] + ']') 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a map or an array of objects instead of two arrays.

Comment: Since you already have all this code, you could just sort `a` by looking up the counts in `b`. It's a pretty bad solution, however and might not be that easy to implement or maintain. A very easy way is to rewrite it completely, since the whole thing can be implemented in less than 10 lines of code by doing `split` -> `reduce` -> `sort`.

Comment: I never use reduce before. I looked it up in Internet. the definition said  "the reduce() method reduces the array to a single value". After I split the user input to array of individual word, how do I use the reduce().  Could you explain it a little bit more about it?  Thank you

Comment: indeed is better with map or reduce ( see my answer )

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

1- insert your data: word and word's count in the same object

2- sort this object using the key `count`

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
<input type="text" id="paragraph" class="field",> 
<button onclick="input()"><b>Submit</b></button>


<script>
function input() {
var test = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
var arr =[];
 arr = test.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").split(/\s+/); 
  /*remove all special characters: there remove anything that's not letter*/
  /*or replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '') --> place all characters you want to avoid here */
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;

function foo(arr) {

    var a = [];
    var new_item;
    var counter=0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        new_item=true;
        for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
           if(a[j]['word']== arr[i]){
               a[j]['count'] ++;
               new_item=false;
           }
        }
       if(new_item){
         a[counter] = {}; a[counter]["word"] = arr[i];a[counter]["count"] = 1;
         counter ++;
       }
       
    }
    a.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt(b.count) - parseInt(a.count);
    });
    return a;
  }

   var result = foo(arr);
   for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ) {
      document.write("you wrote :"+result[i]['word']+" "+result[i]['count']+" times<br/>");
    }
 
   
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Amani, it is really clear and straight forward. Could you explain what is the purpose of using new_item=true and new_item=false ?  Thank you

Comment: while creating the object of words and count words, I checked before inserting a new word if this word already exists in the object by looping all its previous items, if this word is not in the object then I add it if the word exists I will increase the count of this word..

Comment: and it would be better to use `test.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/)` than `test.toLowerCase().split(" ")` like that extra white-space will not be considered as a word.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the suggestions. It is clear now. So if I want to also ignore ( ), !..  these special characters, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved by sorting the array in descending order, as all the elements in array b are relative to elements in array a. For example:- [aaa,hello]
[1,3] denotes 1 frequency of "aaa" and 3 frequency of "hello". If you sort the B array in descending order it will be [3,1] and if you swap all the value of array a in same loop, it will solve the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> practice </title>
<style>
.field{
font-size: 10px; /
width: 400px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<p> This progam will calculate what you want to</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
<input type="text" id="paragraph" class="field",> 
<button onclick="input()"><b>Submit</b></button>


<script>
function input() {
var test = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
var arr =[];
 arr = test.toLowerCase().split(" ");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;

function foo(arr) {

    var a = [], b = [], prev;

    arr.sort();
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }

//Code modification by Dixit starts
     //Sorting the arrays in descending order
     for(i=0;i<b.length; i++)
     {
        for(j=i+1;j<b.length; j++)
        {
            if(b[i] < b[j])
            {
                var temp = b[j];
                b[j] = b[i];
                b[i]= temp;

                var temp1 = a[j];
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i]= temp1;                
            }                       
        }
     }
     //Sorting the arrays in descending order
//Code modification by Dixit ends
   return [a, b];
}

 var result = foo(arr);



    document.write('[' + result[0] + ']<br>[' + result[1] + ']') 
}




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note, I have used bubble sort technique just for an example, and the worst case time complexity is 0(N^2). You can use any sorting techniques depending on the number of inputs.

Comment: Thank you, Dixit. You code solve my problem based on my original codes.  But it seems like I choice a very bad way to figure the problem out. I will try to find a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow my try using [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var test = "a a b c a 4 3 fff 3 9 fff 9 bb"
var arr =[];
 arr = test.toLowerCase().split(" ");


function sortProperties(obj)
{
  // convert object into array
    var sortable=[];
    for(var key in obj)
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            sortable.push([key, obj[key]]); // each item is an array in format [key, value]

    // sort items by value
    sortable.sort(function(a, b)
    {
        var x=a[1],
            y=b[1];
        return x>y ? -1 : x<y ? 1 : 0;
    });
    return sortable; // array in format [ [ key1, val1 ], [ key2, val2 ], ... ]
}

function calculate(myArr) {
var result = {};
    myArr.map(function(item){
      if (!result[item]){
        result[item]=1;
      }
      else {
        result[item]++;
      }
    },result);
    return sortProperties(result);
}

 var result = calculate(arr);
 console.log(result);
```